# What resource should be used when linking to Perl CPAN modules?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Recently there has been an uptick in suggested edits to update hyperlinks to Perl CPAN modules from:

> http://search.cpan.org

to:

> http://metacpan.org/

These edits are being done even though the original link is still working.  Here are a few examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14146610/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/350038/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/502972/revisions

I've found a few discussions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17105/how-should-i-link-to-cpan-modules-in-answers) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76208/how-do-i-efficiently-generate-cpan-links-for-so-answers) that both reference the use of the `http://search.cpan.org` when linking to these modules and this new source is not mentioned?

Is `https://metacpan.org` considered a valid resource for these links?  Many of edits are going through the review queue and getting accepted because the new link is working but I want to be sure that this is a valid resource before rolling back, etc. if necessary.

Comment: You might want to post a link to this in the Perl chat room. (I would, but chat's blocked at work.)

Comment: One reason for this is that cpan.org links often include the version number. As soon as a new version of a module is released, you're no longer pointing to the latest documentation.

Comment: And yes, metacpan is a valid resource...it is simply a different (and more feature-rich) frontend to CPAN. It is actually linked on the main http://www.cpan.org page under "Search CPAN via..."

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot It's a valid resource, yes, but the existing search isn't being deprecated, and there doesn't seem to be anything inherently better about it, either. Unless the search results it provides are super-awesome-mega-better, a suggested edit that doesn't change anything else is almost certainly Too Minor. Possibly even Spam if the person making the suggestions is associated with MetaCPAN.

Comment: @billy metacpan includes links to the CPAN testers results, the changelog, and reviews of a module, all on a single page, among other nice features. The same information is available via search.cpan.org, but another click or two away. So I would say metacpan *is* inherently better. Having said that, I agree that the change is probably too minor for a suggested edit (unless the original link included the module version, in which case it *should* be updated to a non-version-specific URL, be that on search.cpan.org or on metacpan).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot That sounds suspiciously like you could answer this question pretty thoroughly...

Comment: That user has attempted to suggest edits that only change the links 115 times -- of those, only 2 of these link-only edits have been rejected (and 113 approved). Well, the 226 reputation from that is now enough for the user to edit without suggestions...

Comment: Links to CPAN should be to the 'Permalink' which is version independent.

Answer (score 7):

[MetaCPAN](https://metacpan.org/about) provides a richer interface than [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/). Some nice features of MetaCPAN:

- Easy links to POD items, instead of just headers. For example, if I browse to the `LWP::UserAgent` documentation, I can link to the [`post()` method](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-post-url-form-field_name-value) instead of just the [request methods header](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?LWP::UserAgent#REQUEST_METHODS).
- Links to the changelog, CPAN testers results, and module reviews, all on the same page as the documentation. This requires an extra click or two with search.cpan.org.
- Syntax highlighting by default
- URLs don't contain version numbers. URLs on search.cpan.org always contain the module author and version, so people who aren't aware of the "permalink" button end up linking to documentation that becomes stale when the module is updated.

There are [other advantages](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mo/2011/06/introducing-betametacpanorg---a-better-search-for-the-cpan.html), but those are the main ones that I could think of that apply to links on SO.

Except for the case of suggested edits where the link is the only change (too minor), I think these edits are a good thing. And if a URL contains the module version, it should *definitely* be updated (whether to MetaCPAN or to the "canonical" search.cpan.org form doesn't matter) so that users always see the latest documentation.

Comment: This particular edit was flagged as being a bad conversion to MetaCPAN: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/649808/revisions , so I rolled it back for now. Was it a correct edit?

Comment: That edit changed a working link to a broken one, so no, it was not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I use `p3rl.org` (which is a redirector to metacpan). The reasons listed above for MetaCPAN apply, plus:

- It's easy to type (just `[Module::Name](http://p3rl.org/Module::Name)`)
- It's hosted by Juerd, who I trust not to just disappear.
- If anything happens to MetaCPAN, `p3rl.org` can start redirecting somewhere else, and a million links (mostly) won't have to be re-pointed.